# Twilio SMS sent from +12345

Tags: sms, twilio

I am sending SMS using Twilio Node (http://twilio.github.io/twilio-node/).

In the from field I've set the number that Twilio gave me, yet when I receive the SMS it shows as +1 (234) 5.

The only thing I can think of is that I am using the trial account, but their FAQ doesn't say anything about this...

https://www.twilio.com/help/faq/twilio-basics/how-does-twilios-free-trial-work

Code snippet:

```
  // Require and initialize the Twilio module with your credentials
  var client = require('twilio')('A-FAKE-8cc', 'b53090-FAKE-6808');

  // Send an SMS message
  client.sendSms({
      to:'+' + to,
      from: '+15734XXXXXX',
      body: 'Your code is ' + code
    }, function(err, responseData) {
      if (err) {
        console.log(err);
      } else {
        console.log(responseData.from);
        console.log(responseData.body);
      }
    }
  );
```

Here is another piece of info: my twilio number is in the US, while my destination is in Israel - does it matter? Also, when I verified my number I received the code from this +12345 as well.

Confirming my suspicion: I've just verified a US number this time, and it showed the correct number (both from my app and from twilio).

Comment: Twilio evangelist here. Can you show me some code?

Comment: updated question with code snippet

Comment: (Using Parse.com, by the way)

Comment: Hey, have just copied your code exactly, and replaced the credentials with a trial account's credentials. Got a text from my Twilio number. Is the "To" number a verified number?

Comment: Interesting. Here is another piece of info: my twilio number is in the US, while my destination is in Israel - does it matter? Also, when I verified my number I received the code from this +12345 as well.

Comment: Confirming my suspicion: I've just verified a US number this time, and it showed the correct number (both from my app and from twilio)

Comment: Ok, so the problem was that you weren't using a confirmed number then right?

Comment: No no, see my comments. All my numbers are verified. The difference is one is in Israel and the other in the US.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/71491/discussion-between-nathan-h-and-marcos-placona).

Comment: Did you manage to solve this issue? I have similar problem.

Comment: No, but I abandoned my project.

Answer (score 0):

Hey to be very honest your location doesn't matter to have a call on the Twilio platform apart from that if you want to have an upgraded account i'll suggest you to apply for Github's student developer program you'll get 50$ from that and you can buy some virtual numbers from that.

And to successfully make calls i am linking a repository which will help you in sending messages as well as calls over the internet.[Getting started with Twilio at MLH INIT](https://github.com/TwilioQuest/mlh-init-getting-started)